# How to play HLS stream in VLC

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to play a HLS stream in WPF using Vlc.DotNet, but I keep getting 403 Forbidden error. I can however download the m3u8 file through browser and it also does play with https://www.hlsplayer.net/. I just cannot get it to work with VLC or any other media player software.
Do I perhaps need to send some headers with the request? Is there any other media player library that can handle HTTP live streaming?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that the stream uses cookies for authentication and VLC does not support them directly. I managed to get it to work using StreamPlayerControl library.
https://github.com/jacobbo/WebEye/tree/master/StreamPlayerControl